# Is it possible to run a single Steak test in RubyMine?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rubymine, acceptance-testing

I've recently migrated from TextMate to RubyMine and have really liked it so far.  One thing I noticed was that RubyMine doesn't have a Steak plugin like TextMate does, which allows the ability to run a single scenario.

Is there any way to do the same in RubyMine or am I stuck running the full file of acceptance tests everytime I want to run a single Steak test?

Answer (score 0):

Steak is an extension for rspec. To run single tests in rspec you can specify a `--tag`

```
describe 'run this test', :focus => true do
  # this one will run
end

describe 'but not this one' do
  # wont get run
end

$ rspec --tag focus my_spec_file.rb
```

(Note: I've never used rubymine)

Comment: Thanks this should definitely work, but ideally I'd be able to run the single test directly from RubyMine without having to modify the test itself.  RubyMine has a hotkey that works within Rspec "it" blocks but not within steak "scenario" blocks.

Comment: Also is this option compatible with RSpec 1.3.2?  I can't seem to get it to work, probably because we're on an old version